# Re-create Rapidweaver project from published files

Tags: projects-and-solutions

I have been tasked with maintaining a site that someone else created with Rapidweaver. Unfortunately, I only have the files that were published to the website. The Rapidweaver project files are gone. Is there any way I can re-create a Rapidweaver project from the published files?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is too late, but for anyone else out there with a similar question, you CANNOT recreate a Rapidweaver project from the published files. Now, looking at the code, you might be able to figure out which theme was used and start from scratch, but that is the best you are going to be able to do. Rapidweaver firstly depends on themes, but there are also many other plugins that could be used, and if you do not have these plugins or themes already installed, you would not be able to edit the original project file, much less the exported website.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is one way of getting it back. Use a program called "sitesucker" to download the entire site on to your hard drive. Look for a folder called "rw_resources" (NOT plain resources). You will find two subfolders "themes" and "plugins". Upon dropping down, there will be a folder by the name of the theme in the "theme" folder and folders with the name of the plugins in the "plugins" folder. Buy and install rapidweaver, stacks, plugins and theme. Create a blank project file. Open this project file in finder. Go back to the folder of the website you sucked out. Carefully transfer the relevant files to the blank project file. DO NOT mess with the "theme.plist" or "info.plist" files. Close the .rwsw sandwich. Restart rapidweaver. Your "blank" project should now be a recreation of the original site.

Comment: can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @captainrad I realize this is a little late to the game, but he's not completely wrong. You _might_ be able to download the theme by grabbing all those files, but I doubt it (I think you'd have to have the theme installed locally or recreate the bundle from the raw files), but even if you had the theme, you'd have to recreate each existing page in RW, and you'd have to create each page as an html format page and paste in the content from the files you downloaded, but only the content between the content markers (eg, `<!-- Start content -->`). It would be a painful, non-trivial task.